# Simple code completion sample in Roslyn

Tags: c#, code-completion, roslyn

I'd like to get started with code completion in Roslyn but could not find any simple examples that show how to do code completion.

What would be a good example to finish this code so that I can obtain all possible completion items (AKA Intellisense or CTRL+Space completion) at the `caretIndex`?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var code = @"
    using System;
    public class Test
    {
        public void TestMethod()
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            now.
        }
    }";
    Console.WriteLine(code);

    var st = SyntaxTree.ParseText(code);
    var caretIndex = code.IndexOf("now.") + 4;

    //how to get possible code completions at caret index? (Intellisense)
}
```

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I don't think that it's going to be as easy as "ask Roslyn what you could type after that".

Comment: You're trying to get intellisense results for current `caretIndex` value?

Comment: At the very least, you will need a semantic tree.

Comment: Yep, I think if it's anything like NRefactory you'd have to setup a `Workspace`, then add the document, and then setup some kind of code completion factory where you can ask what comes after the curet... but I'm not sure how it's done.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Yes exactly, I'd like to get intellisense at the `caretIndex`.

Comment: Roslyn will give you the type of token. You will have to use Reflection to get the members of this type. But it could be tough to get the extension methods.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes okey... but then what about extension methods etc, and what if you want to do Intellisense on a blank line, e.g., to see what types are available? Is there no API that simplifies code completion? In NRefactory you have this completion engine: https://github.com/lukebuehler/NRefactory-Completion-Sample/blob/master/Src/ICSharpCode.CodeCompletion/CSharpCompletion.cs#L128

Comment: You will have to get the referenced assemblies (I don't know if Roslyn tells you that) and go through the exported types of these assemblies.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Roslyn does provide code completion services through the `ICompletionService` and `ICompletionProvider` interfaces, but they seem to mostly be internal and meant to be accessed when hosted within Visual Studio. However, it is possible to get a hold of the C# code completion types using a couple of reflection hacks, as illustrated by the [ScriptCS Pad](https://github.com/khellang/scriptcs-editor/tree/master/ScriptCsPad) project. If you can get this to work, I expect you should get VS-grade code completion.

Alternatively, you can do it "by hand", using the public APIs provided by Roslyn. I am not well-versed in them, but the following should get you started in listing the members of the expression to the left of the member access dot. Note that it ignores extension methods and visibility rules, does no error handling and is probably flawed in many other ways. Doing this reliably probably doesn't qualify as "simple" code completion, though.

```
var code = @"
    using System;
    public class Test
    {
        public void TestMethod()
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            now.
        }
    }";
Console.WriteLine(code);

var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code);
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("foo")
    .AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateAssemblyReference(typeof(DateTime).Assembly.FullName))
    .AddSyntaxTrees(syntaxTree);
var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(syntaxTree);

var dotTextSpan = new TextSpan(code.IndexOf("now.") + 3, 1);
var memberAccessNode = (MemberAccessExpressionSyntax)syntaxTree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes(dotTextSpan).Last();

var lhsType = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(memberAccessNode.Expression).Type;

foreach (var symbol in lhsType.GetMembers())
{
    if (!symbol.CanBeReferencedByName
        || symbol.DeclaredAccessibility != Accessibility.Public
        || symbol.IsStatic)
        continue;

    Console.WriteLine(symbol.Name);
}
```

**EDIT**: Note that this answer was probably made obsolete by the new Roslyn bits.

Comment: I don't think your answer was made obsolete. Most of the code completion APIs are still internal only, AFAIK. Hence the work NRefactory does with Roslyn now...

Comment: @lukebuehler Maybe, but I found the `SemanticModel.LookupSymbols` method which seems to do most of the work. I'm not sure if it's new or not though.

Answer (score 4):

Provided you have a `Workspace` instance, you can use public recommendation API from `Microsoft.CodeAnalysys.Workspaces` package:

```
public static class Recommender
{
     public static IEnumerable<ISymbol> GetRecommendedSymbolsAtPosition(SemanticModel semanticModel, int position, Workspace workspace, OptionSet options = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
}
```

It returns completion symbols at given offset. It does not return keywords, but as of march 2016 Roslyn guys are working on better public api for completion: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/3538